# IllegalStateException Caused by in-app billing checkNotDisposed

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I implemented in-app purchase for my Android app. The in-app purchase function work fine on both my device and emulator. However, after the app was uploaded to Google Play, I received this crash report on my Google Play Developer Console, as an issue facing by my users.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

  at inappbilling.util.IabHelper.checkNotDisposed (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .flagStartAsync (IabHelper.java)

  at inappbilling.util.IabHelper.checkSetupDone (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .flagEndAsync (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .getResponseCodeFromBundle (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .getResponseCodeFromIntent (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .getResponseDesc (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .handleActivityResult (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .launchPurchaseFlow (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .queryInventory (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .queryInventoryAsync (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .queryPurchases (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .querySkuDetails (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .startSetup (IabHelper.java)

  at inappbilling.util.IabHelper.checkSetupDone (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .flagEndAsync (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .getResponseCodeFromBundle (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .getResponseCodeFromIntent (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .getResponseDesc (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .handleActivityResult (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .launchPurchaseFlow (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .queryInventory (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .queryInventoryAsync (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .queryPurchases (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .querySkuDetails (IabHelper.java)
  or                     .startSetup (IabHelper.java)
```

My `IabHelper` was called in `onCreate`.

```
String base64EncodedPublicKey = 
                                       "<license key here>";

            mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

            mHelper.startSetup(new 
            IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                 public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
             {
                       if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                         Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: " + 
                    result);
                       } else {             
                         Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                   }
                     }
            });
```

This is the my Purchase Finished Listener:

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
            = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                          Purchase purchase)
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                checkItem();
                return;
            }
            else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
                removeAds();
            }

        }
    };
```

And my Query Inventory Finished:

```
public void checkItem() {
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
    }

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
            = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                             Inventory inventory) {

            if (mHelper == null) return;
            Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU);
            if (purchase != null) {
                removeAds();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: I got the same trace
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at billingutil.IabHelper.checkSetupDone (IabHelper.java:879)
  at billingutil.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow (IabHelper.java:438)
  at billingutil.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow (IabHelper.java:400)
  at londonteam.colonize.StoreActivity.launchPurchase (StoreActivity.java:375)

Answer (score 0):

Are you definition item in your google play panel?
Do you installed google play to your device's?

Comment: I myself do not face any issue. This problem is faced by my users who installed my app. As all of them downloaded my app through google play and the crash report was showed in Google Play console, I think all of them have google play services.